# Typing on a path and object fill disappears

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text-on-path

When I type along the object path the colour fill 'pink' disappears! I have tried to refill the colour by selecting the pink drop layer but it changes the 'celebrating' text instead!

[image]

Comment: The green drop is above the purple one in the screenshot.

Comment: Hi yes this is supposed to be like that - its the pink drop that its supposed to be below (you can't see the actual pink drop colour here due to the problem with the text path which is my second question) thanks

Comment: if the pink drop is below, you won't see its color where the green one overlaps it - unless the green drop is transparent, and it will look different depending on the blending mode

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back to me again - i'm not sure i'm explaining myself correctly - but in the layers window you can see the green drop is positioned below the pink drop. However when the pink drop is visible (its not on the screenshot i gave as the text path wiped out its colour) the green drop is actually on top of the pink and not below - so its not equating to the order on the layers window. Thanks

Comment: so definitely check the blending mode / transparency settings for the objects and layers

Comment: Hi E Cummin, I've removed the first part of your question; please limit your question to a single question at a time (the first issue isn't even visible because of the second so there's not much anyone can say about it) If you're still having issues with the layers you can open another question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help]. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When you attach text to a path, the fill and stroke of the object disappears, this is normal behaviour. That's what is supposed to happen.

If you want to keep the shape/path, you'll need to create a duplicate to type on.

This screenshot may help:

[image: Text on a Pth]

Comment: OK thanks so essentially make two drops the same and place one on top of the other? Also re the layering question -  - its the pink drop that its supposed to be below (you can't see the actual pink drop colour here due to the problem with the text path which is my second question) thanks

Comment: Yeah, you got it. I added a screenshot to help you. Two objects, one for the path - in this example gradient filled ellipse, and a copy of the ellipse that I typed on.  You can use Copy and then Paste in Front - so that the copy is right on top, in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Type on a Path tool will remove all styling from that path; there is no way (as far as I know) to stop that from happening.... like this:

[image]

You can however, just reselect that same path and reapply your styling:

[image]

Select *the path itself* or one of its anchors using the Direct Selection tool (the white arrow); it should say "Anchor Point" at the top left of the control bar (if it says "Type", you've selected the type instead; deselect and try again).